# hive select max count by grouping on two fields

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to write a sql query to find Most Popular Artist in each Country. Popular artist is one which has maximum number of rating>=8

Below is table structure,

```
describe album;
albumid                string                                      
album_title              string                                      
album_artist             string`                             

describe album_ratings;
userid                  int                                         
albumid              string                                      
rating             int                                         

describe cusers;
userid                  int                                         
state                   string                                      
country                 string
```

Below is one query that I wrote but it is not working.

```
select album_artist, country, count(rating) 
from album, album_ratings, cusers 
where album.albumid=album_ratings.albumid 
      and album_ratings.userid=cusers.userid 
      and rating>=6 
group by country, album_artist 
having count(rating) = (
                        select max(t.cnt) 
                        from (
                              select count(rating) as cnt 
                              from album, album_ratings, cusers 
                              where album.albumid=album_ratings.albumid 
                              and album_ratings.userid=cusers.userid 
                              and rating>=6 
                              group by country, album_artist
                             ) as t 
                        group by t.country
                        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

You can do this with window functions:

```
select *
from (select album_artist, country, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by country order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from album a join
           album_ratings ar join
           on a.albumid = ar.albumid 
           cusers u
           on ar.userid = u.userid 
      where rating >= 6 
      group by country, album_artist 
     ) aru
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want ties, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `row_number` to find most popular artist in each country (higher rating - more popular):

```
select *
from (
    select c.country, 
        a.album_artist,
        sum(rating) as total_rating,
        row_number() over (partition by c.country order by sum(rating) desc) as rn
    from cusers c
    join album_ratings r on c.userid = r.userid
    join album a on r.albumid = a.albumid
    where r.rating >= 8
    group by c.country, 
        a.album_artist
    ) t
where rn = 1;
```

I assumed sum(rating) instead, because I think rating should be additive.

Also, always use explicit join syntax instead of old comma based join.